# How to fix a jQuery code looping incorrectly in a PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, jquery, foreach, advanced-custom-fields, attr

I'm trying to loop a piece of jQuery code inside a foreach loop. Each article in the loop have a phone number custom post type related (ACF). At this point the loop works well.

As you see, the jQuery code only replace an image to another while user clicks in order to show the number (Ex : "Display Phone Number" image, becomes "555-555-1234").

The problem is that when I click in any image to display number...all articles show their phone number at the same time. I think is an ID problem in my jQuery code. After two days of searching and testing different codes this problem still not resolved yet.

Any suggestions/tracks will be very welcome !

Thanks

====

Things I have tried :

1. I have tried to put the jQuery code outside the foreach (same result)
2. I have tried to change the id image into a class (works better)
3. I have tried different jQuery functions (`replaceWith()`, `show()`, etc)

```php
foreach ($related_posts_articles as $related_post ){

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xs-12">

        <div>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($related_post->ID); ?> ">
                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($related_post->ID,"square-300",array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?>   
            </a>
            <div>
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($related_post->ID); ?>">
                    <h2>
                        <?php echo wp_html_excerpt(strip_tags(get_field('acf_titre_mini', $related_post->ID)), 30, '...' ); ?>
                    </h2>
                </a>
                <div>
                    <?php echo wp_html_excerpt( strip_tags(get_field('acf_description_mini',$related_post->ID)), 129, '...' ); ?>    
                </div>

                <!-- START bloc number -->
                <?php if( get_field('acf_numero_image', $related_post->ID) ): ?>
                    <div>
                        <img class="input_img" src="<?php the_field('acf_btnVoirNum_image', $related_post->ID); ?>" >
                        <script>
                            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                                $( ".input_img" ).click(function() {
                                    $( ".input_img" ).attr( "src", "<?php the_field('acf_numero_image', $related_post->ID); ?>" );
                                });
                            });
                        </script>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <!-- END bloc number -->

            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take note of the 'this' Context

When an event fires in jquery the callback function `this` context is set to the element which the event was fired from.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".input_img").click(function() {
        // Use `this` to target the event element
        $(this).attr("src", "<?php the_field('acf_numero_image', $related_post->ID); ?>" );
    });
});
```

Advice:
You shouldn't generate same jquery code inside each iteration of the `for each`. Since you're repeating unnecessary code. You can harness HTML [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) attributes to achieve the outcome you seek.

Comment: It works ! This solves the user click display event, thanks. Have an idea how to target the spefic number of each post, it shows the same number everywhere.

Comment: @Nick83 Can you expand on your issue a bit more? If an answer has solved the original question I would advise you mark it. This helps others who may have this issue in the future.

Comment: Riddell Each post in a foreach as a different ACF image number in a variable called 'acf_numero_image'. While clicking in "Display Phone Number" of any post, the same image number is shown. My code doesn't target the ACF varible to show the correct image.

Comment: @Nick83 I would suggest making new question for this. I remember having this issue a few years ago and using `wp_reset_postdata()` this may help https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/get-count-of-same-values-in-an-array/

Comment: I finally get the complet code working ! @Riddell thanks for the ACF link and solving the first part of my script. The final code is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57728343/how-to-target-an-acf-field-in-a-jquery-code-inside-%c3%a0-foreach-loop?noredirect=1#comment101946457_57728343

Answer (score 1):

You are giving the class name the same for all images. Also by looping you are adding lot's of scripts. You can add Onclick events to image and create a function and grab the data and do you things. Also, you can add extra attributes to img tag to get your data. Also try to put different ID like below,

```
foreach ($related_posts_articles as $key=>$related_post ){
 <img id="img-<?php echo $key; ?>" onclick="myFunction(this)" class="input_img" src="<?php the_field('acf_btnVoirNum_image', $related_post->ID); ?>" >
}
```