# How to target an ACF field in a jQuery code inside à foreach loop?

Tags: jquery, advanced-custom-fields, attr

How to target an ACF field in a jQuery code inside à foreach loop ?

Currently, posts are looping in a foreach loop. Each post presents a coach with photo, title, small description and a phone number. All of this elements are ACF custom fields which need to be filled in a back-office for each person.

At this point it's all right.

Phone number of each coach is hidden, the user needs to click on a button (which is an image "Show Number") to see the phone (which is another image as well). I'm using the .attr() jQuery function to replace the first image by the second one.

The problem : when the user clicks on any "Show Number" image, the last image number is displayed.

Expectation (Ex : Nicolas as 555-555-555 | Andrea as 555-485-784 | Melody as 555-124-332)
Currently   (Ex : Nicolas as 555-124-332 | Andrea as 555-124-332 | Melody as 555-124-332)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
foreach ($related_posts_articles as $related_post ){

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xs-12">

        <div>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($related_post->ID); ?> ">
                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($related_post->ID,"square-300",array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?>   
            </a>
            <div>
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($related_post->ID); ?>">
                    <h2>
                        <?php echo wp_html_excerpt(strip_tags(get_field('acf_titre_mini', $related_post->ID)), 30, '...' ); ?>
                    </h2>
                </a>
                <div>
                    <?php echo wp_html_excerpt( strip_tags(get_field('acf_description_mini',$related_post->ID)), 129, '...' ); ?>    
                </div>

                <!-- START bloc -->
                <?php if( get_field('acf_numero_image', $related_post->ID) ): ?>
                    <div align="center">
                        <img class="input_img" src="<?php the_field('acf_btnVoirNum_image', $related_post->ID); ?>" >
                        <script>
                            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                                $(".input_img").click(function() {
                                    $(this).attr("src", "<?php the_field('acf_numero_image', $related_post->ID); ?>" );
                                });
                            });
                        </script>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <!-- END bloc -->
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>

}
```

Comment: Probably because you're adding multiple `$(".input_img").click(function() ...` functions in your `foreach` loop. Move the JavaScript outside the loop, give `.input_img` elements a custom attribute (e.g. `data-acf-numero-image="whatever"`), then use that value for the `.attr("src", value)` part.

Comment: @user7290573 Thanks for the msg. While giving a custom attribute for .input_img, you mean inside the jQuery code or in the <img> class ?  In data-acf-numero-image="whatever" it's possible to store an URL (e.g. data-acf-numero-image="<?php the_field('acf_numero_image', $related_post->ID); ?>" ?

Comment: Yes, exactly - try changing to `<img class="input_img" src="<?php the_field('acf_btnVoirNum_image', $related_post->ID); ?>" data-acf-numero-image="<?php the_field('acf_numero_image', $related_post->ID); ?>" />`, then just use *one* `.click()` handler for your images.

Comment: @user7290573 Ok - I tried this : <img class="img-responsive input_img" src="<?php the_field('acf_btnVoirNum_image', $related_post->ID); ?>" data-acf-numero-image="<?php the_field('acf_numero_image', $related_post->ID); ?>" onclick="input_img[this.dataset.acfNumeroImage];"> but no result. when you say just using one '.click()' it means in the img tag and not in the jQuery code, right ? I think that I'm doing something wrong in the syntax.

Comment: I've posted an answer for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem : when the user clicks on any "Show Number" image, the last image number is displayed.

This is because you're adding a `.click()` handler in every iteration of your loop where `if( get_field('acf_numero_image', $related_post->ID) )` is truthy, specifically this part:

```
$(".input_img").click(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", "<?php the_field('acf_numero_image', $related_post->ID); ?>" );
});
```

If you view the page source for your rendered HTML, it's going to look something like the following:

```
<!-- loop 1 -->
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".input_img").click(function() {
            $(this).attr("src", "some_image_1.jpg" );
        });
    });
</script>

<!-- loop 2 -->
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".input_img").click(function() {
            $(this).attr("src", "some_image_2.jpg" );
        });
    });
</script>

<!-- loop 3 -->
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".input_img").click(function() {
            $(this).attr("src", "some_image_3.jpg" );
        });
    });
</script>

<!-- etc. -->
```

Because you're adding another `.click()` handler every loop, when you click on `.input_img`, it's going to go through each of your `click` handlers and change the `src` to `some_image_1.jpg`, then `some_image_2.jpg`, and so on, until it reaches the *last* one, hence why it appears to only display the last image number.

Using a custom `data-` attribute and moving the `.click()` handler outside of the loop will fix this - abridged example below:

```
<?php
    foreach ($related_posts_articles as $related_post) {

        // wrapper <div> / other HTML here

        ?>
            <!-- START bloc -->
            <?php if (get_field('acf_numero_image', $related_post->ID)): ?>
                <div align="center">

                    <!--
                        Adding custom data-acf-numero-image attribute here containing field value
                    -->
                    <img class="input_img" src="<?php the_field('acf_btnVoirNum_image', $related_post->ID); ?>" data-acf-numero-image="<?php the_field('acf_numero_image', $related_post->ID); ?>" />

                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <!-- END bloc -->
        <?php

        // closing <div> elements here
    }
?>

<!--
    One single block of JS to handle all clicks to .input_img, rather than adding
    duplicate click handlers inside the foreach loop:
-->
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".input_img").click(function() {
            // Get "acf_numero_image" value from custom data- attribute
            var acfNumeroImage = $(this).attr("data-acf-numero-image");

            // Update src attribute with custom acf_numero_image
            $(this).attr("src", acfNumeroImage);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The code works perfectly ! Thanks a lot for your time ! The part that I missed was : var acfNumeroImage = $(this).attr("data-acf-numero-image"); and updating the src attribute with "acfNumeroImage".

Comment: No problem. I hope you understand what the problem was, i.e. creating several `.click()` handlers - it looks like someone warned you about this in your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57723598/7290573

Comment: You are right. @Riddell gave the advice of using data-*. I didn't search enough ! I'll  take time to consider users answers in the future. Thanks again.